# ¿Cómo puedo asociar el avatar de un usuario en un post que éste realice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy tratando de crear un blog que permita a los usuarios registrados crear nuevos posts. Mi principal problema es tratar de recuperar la imagen de perfil (avatar) del usuario que crea el post. La imagen de perfil se encuentra en el modelo de la app ¨registration¨ y el sistema de post se encuentra en la app ¨pages¨, tal como se menciona a continuación. Cualquier ayuda se agradece!

models.py (registration)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    old_instance = Profile.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    old_instance.avatar.delete()
    return 'profiles/' + filename

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user__username']

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def ensure_profile_exists(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

models.py (pages)

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.models import Profile

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Título", max_length=200)                             # Titulo 
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name="autor", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Contenido")                                           # Contenido 
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Orden", default=0)                           # Orden de publicacion
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")         # Fecha de creacion
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de edición")              # Fecha de actualizacion


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "página"
        verbose_name_plural = "páginas"
        ordering = ['order', 'title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py (pages)

```
from .models import Page
from django.views.generic.list import ListView 
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from .forms import PageForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from registration.models import Profile

#Decoradores
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
class StaffRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(StaffRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PageListView(ListView):
    model = Page

@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Page

# CRUD: 
@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class PageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Page 
    form_class = PageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.post = form.save(commit=False)
        self.post.author =  self.request.user
        self.post.save()
        return super(PageCreate, self).form_valid(form)

@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class PageUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Page
    form_class = PageForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('pages:update', args=[self.object.id]) + '?ok'

@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class PageDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Page
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que necesitas hacer esto en un template, para hacer esto debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<img src="{{ page.author.profile.avatar.url }}">
```

Para que esto funcione apropiadamente debes tener bien configuradas las variables `MEDIA` en el archivo `settings.py`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Hola Saul, y gracias por responder. El problema que tengo no es referirme directamente al avatar del usuario, si no que al momento de que este (usuario) cree un post en el blog la aplicación pueda reconocer al usuario que realizó el posteo y automaticamente asignarle su foto actual de perfil. Estoy trabajando con CBV (Class Based Views) por lo que creo que el camino es actuar directamente en el ´ListView´o ´DetailView´ por medio de una función get_context_data() para que realice esta acción. Aún no lo he resuelto del todo, pero si conoces algo de esta referencia estaré atento. Gracias!

Comment: Me puedes explicar para que necesitas recuperar el avatar, no me queda claro. Veo que en la clase `PageCreate` estás recuperando el usuario con `self.request.user`, en ese caso puedes hacer `self.request.user.profile.avatar`.

Comment: Mi idea es mostrar al igual que, por ejemplo, Facebook que al momento de hacer un post muestra al usuario y su foto de perfil. Pero esta foto de perfil cambia cada vez que el usuario cambia su foto. Tal como mencionas, debo recuperar la foto del usuario, pero lo que no intuyo es ¿cómo asocio la foto al usuario que realizó el post? Seguiré probando lo que me dices de recuperar desde el request.user. Gracias